# Is there a way to reference VM in xaml while using AutoWireViewModel = "True"

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism, mahapps.metro

As you see, I'm trying a new way to show custom dialog with MahApp.Metro in MVVM.

I can't reference `MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs` in VM directly for using
`dialogCoordinator.ShowMetroDialogAsync(..., BaseMetroDialog dialog, ...)`, 
because `BaseMetroDialog` is an UI element(breaking MVVM).

So I'm trying define my custom dialog in xaml, then calling `ShowMetroDialogAsync` via `ObjectDataProvider`. But I don't know how to get reference of `DataContext(the VM)` for passing to `ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters` as the first param.

[image]

button for trigger `ObjectDataProvider`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with a a service that shows the dialog. This way, the view model does not know of the view and you do not need over-complicated xaml constructs.

Or you go for prism's built-in popup system with interaction requests.

Comment: calling `dialogCoordinator.ShowMetroDialogAsync` in VM means you must new an instance of `BaseMetroDialog` in VM's command, or you must using 'MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs' namespace in VM for accessing Dialog.DataContext to pass param in it. I think the encapsulation of 'dialogCoordinator.ShowMetroDialogAsync' is incorrect, it exposed UI elements.

Comment: Not in the view model, in a service provided to the view model. The view model just calls the service and has no idea about view stuff. The service knows the view types, but that's fine. Noone says there must not be ui services... `IRegionManager`, `ViewModelLocator`...

Comment: So I need to declare an `BaseMetroDialog` in xaml, then pass it to the service as 
 a `CommandParamater` via command, even the type of `CommandParamater` declare as an `object` ?

Comment: `object` is universal, you could do that. Or you put it into the service altogether and design the dialog in the service and just call `IDialogService.ShowMySpecialDialog`. Also, you should take a look at the popup system in Prism, which may be more sensible if you show lots of different dialogs. `PopupWindowAction` is the starting point.

Comment: I took a quick look at "popup system in Prism", it doesn't seem easy to make it compatible with MetroStyle Dialog of Mahapps.Metro design.

Comment: Not sure about MahApps dialogs, but normally it's easy as setting `WindowContent`. In the worst case you have to copy `PopupWindowAction.cs` and replace `Window` with whatever replacement MahApps uses for its dialogs.

Comment: Thanks your guide. I'll try it.